# baseURL fix in IE

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-app-bootstrap

I'm developing a website with following structure: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oek9I.jpg). And I'm having some problems with the URL when trying to load stylesheets. Being more specific, in the *admin* module I'm using this bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initResources() {
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->headScript()
                ->appendFile('public/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')
                ->appendFile('public/js/jquery.tools.min.js')
                ->appendFile('public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js')
                ->appendFile('public/js/utils.js')
                ->appendFile('public/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
                ->appendFile('public/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')
                ->appendFile('public/js/admin.js')
                ->appendFile('public/js/ie.utils.js', null, array('conditional' => 'IE'))
                ->appendFile('public/js/ie.js', null, array('conditional' => 'IE'));

        $view->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/blueprint/screen.css', 'screen')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/uploadify.css', 'screen')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/jquery.tools.css', 'screen')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/ui-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css', 'screen')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/blueprint/print.css', 'print')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/admin.css', 'screen')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/blueprint/ie.css', 'screen', 'IE')
                ->appendStylesheet('public/css/ie.css', 'screen', 'IE');
    }

}
```

Also I'm using `<base href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/" />` which works perfectly for *Chrome* and *Firefox*, but in *IE* I could see that the `<base>` TAG doesn't work and it uses `/ccgss/admin/` as *baseUrl* instead of `/ccgss/` which cause problem when trying to load something in the `public` folder 'cause it tries to find in `/ccgss/admin/public`.

Is there any other way to append my resources in the bootstrap or I do need to workaround? How this should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set paths like that:

```
 $view->headScript()
                ->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . 'public/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js');
```

also try to use google's jquery store: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

ps: http://code.google.com/intl/en-En/apis/libraries/devguide.html

pss: in my application I use plugins for loading such libraries and I found that it is very useful property for me:

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = /test/
```

Comment: What if I'm setting this in the Bootstrap? `$this->baseUrl()` doesn't work. It says: `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception: Invalid method "baseUrl"`

Comment: if you use it in Bootstrap you can set baseUrl via config - resources.frontController.baseUrl = /test/

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to put a slash in front of those path wich would make them absolute to your websites root.

also from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp):

> In HTML the  tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML the  tag must be
> properly closed.

So make sure you set the right doctype.

Also why is your index.php not in the public folder? You know that the public folder really is the public_html folder on a lot of servers.

Comment: But then, as soon as I upload it to my host, for example, it won't work, making it not portable

Comment: Is there any way to get the baseUrl in the bootstrap? 'cause even fixing the `base`tag, IE still doesn't work